# MapView to show all annotations and zoom in as much as possible of the map

Tags: swift, mkmapview, zooming

I basically have a map where I add two annotations and they are shown as expected.

Then I´m using the following code:

```
let annotations = [start, end]
mapView?.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: false)
```

And this zooms to show my map with the two annotations, but the map could be zoomed in much more and show a more detailed map view.

[This is what I get today](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOpbv.png) and [this is the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRERV.png) that I want.

As you can see the map could be zoomed in a lot more.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 25):

Use this:

```
extension MKMapView {
    /// when we call this function, we have already added the annotations to the map, and just want all of them to be displayed.
    func fitAll() {
        var zoomRect            = MKMapRectNull;
        for annotation in annotations {
            let annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
            let pointRect       = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.01, 0.01);
            zoomRect            = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
        }
        setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 100, 100, 100), animated: true)
    }

    /// we call this function and give it the annotations we want added to the map. we display the annotations if necessary
    func fitAll(in annotations: [MKAnnotation], andShow show: Bool) {
        var zoomRect:MKMapRect  = MKMapRectNull

        for annotation in annotations {
            let aPoint          = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
            let rect            = MKMapRectMake(aPoint.x, aPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1)

            if MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect) {
                zoomRect = rect
            } else {
                zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, rect)
            }
        }
        if(show) {
            addAnnotations(annotations)
        }
        setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 100, bottom: 100, right: 100), animated: true)
    }

}
```

then, after creating an outlet for your MapView, for example as `map`, and with you annotations either added to the map of in an array called `annotations`, access the above methods like so:

```
map.fitAll()
```

OR

```
map.fitAll(in:annotations, true)
```

*respectively*.

Use true or false in the last statement depending on whether you had added the annotations to the map before or not...

Answer (score 25):

Swift 5.0 / 4.2 version of [nyxee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44410698/5544222)

```
extension MKMapView {

    /// When we call this function, we have already added the annotations to the map, and just want all of them to be displayed.
    func fitAll() {
        var zoomRect            = MKMapRect.null;
        for annotation in annotations {
            let annotationPoint = MKMapPoint(annotation.coordinate)
            let pointRect       = MKMapRect(x: annotationPoint.x, y: annotationPoint.y, width: 0.01, height: 0.01);
            zoomRect            = zoomRect.union(pointRect);
        }
        setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 100, bottom: 100, right: 100), animated: true)
    }

    /// We call this function and give it the annotations we want added to the map. we display the annotations if necessary
    func fitAll(in annotations: [MKAnnotation], andShow show: Bool) {
        var zoomRect:MKMapRect  = MKMapRect.null
    
        for annotation in annotations {
            let aPoint          = MKMapPoint(annotation.coordinate)
            let rect            = MKMapRect(x: aPoint.x, y: aPoint.y, width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
        
            if zoomRect.isNull {
                zoomRect = rect
            } else {
                zoomRect = zoomRect.union(rect)
            }
        }
        if(show) {
            addAnnotations(annotations)
        }
        setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 100, bottom: 100, right: 100), animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: it works even though it does not have the green tick.

Answer (score 17):

In Swift:

```
self.mapView.showAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations, animated: true)
```

This is what I use to show all annotations. almost the same as you are doing yes. the map zoom this to fit the visible or usable section of the map, on my app the zoom is good and does add some padding so that none of the pins are touching the edges.

so possibly once the maps is done you can quickly use setVisibleMapRect:edgePadding:animated: using the new visibleRect with a negative padding.

Comment: your solution is much better than extension Mapview solution per my personal request .

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5.3 version with adjustable padding.

```html
extension MKMapView {
    
    func fitAllAnnotations(with padding: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 100, bottom: 100, right: 100)) {
        var zoomRect: MKMapRect = .null
        annotations.forEach({
            let annotationPoint = MKMapPoint($0.coordinate)
            let pointRect = MKMapRect(x: annotationPoint.x, y: annotationPoint.y, width: 0.01, height: 0.01)
            zoomRect = zoomRect.union(pointRect)
        })
        
        setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: padding, animated: true)
    }
    
    func fit(annotations: [MKAnnotation], andShow show: Bool, with padding: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 100, bottom: 100, right: 100)) {
        var zoomRect: MKMapRect = .null
        annotations.forEach({
            let aPoint = MKMapPoint($0.coordinate)
            let rect = MKMapRect(x: aPoint.x, y: aPoint.y, width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
            zoomRect = zoomRect.isNull ? rect : zoomRect.union(rect)
        })
        
        if show {
            addAnnotations(annotations)
        }
        
        setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: padding, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: And a SwiftUI version please :-)